# Wrong order of restored items in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I'm using RecyclerView as a base for my data list and in my adapter the elements are added to the list. The list will always have maximum 10 elements in a specified order. Here is the add method of my adapter:

```
void addResult(Result result) {
    int resultPosition = result.getType().getPos();
    boolean inserted = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
        Result currentField = results.get(i);
        if (currentField.getType().getPos() > resultPosition) {
            results.add(i, result);
            inserted = true;
            notifyItemInserted(i);
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!inserted) {
        results.add(result);
        notifyItemInserted(results.size());
    }
}
```

The list is stored in my fragment to have the data also after a configuration change. Therefore I just use the following method in the adapter:

```
    public void setResults(List<Result> results) {
    this.results = results;
}
```

But after a device rotation the items are displayed in the wrong order. Did I forgot something?

EDIT:

This is the rest of my adapter:

```
    @Override
public ResultHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, viewGroup, false);
    return new ResultHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ResultHolder resultHolder, int position) {
    Result result = results.get(position);
    resultHolder.bindResultData(result);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return results.size();
}
```

Comment: Please add code of your adapter

Comment: I edited my post

Answer (score 2):

When you add an item into the middle of the list, the index of all items which is behind the item that you've just added will be updated.

Try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
    Result currentField = results.get(i);
    if (currentField.getType().getPos() > resultPosition) {
        results.add(i, result);
        inserted = true;
        notifyItemInserted(i);
        notifyItemRangeInserted(i, results.size - i);
        break;
    }
}
```

This could get your stuff done. But using `notify` in a loop is not a good approach. I suggest doing like this:

```
void addResult(Result result) {
    int resultPosition = result.getType().getPos();
    boolean inserted = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
        Result currentField = results.get(i);
        if (currentField.getType().getPos() > resultPosition) {
            results.add(i, result);
            inserted = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (inserted) {
        // I don't know your requirement, so I will use this function
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    } else {
        results.add(result);
        notifyItemInserted(results.size());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but it does not work. With your first suggestion I'm getting a IndexOutOfBoundsException and with the second suggestion the items are still in the wrong order if after device rotation.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is don't iterate through your list of results using the **position** passed by the `onBindViewHolder`.

Instead call `getItemViewType(position)` and use this to iterate through your list, after you return the position associated with each view holder:

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

The truth is your view holder is not saved in a sequential order and unrelated with the ordering provided by the `onBindViewHolder`. By calling the `getItemViewHolder` you're essentially associating the positions to each view holder.

Comment: Whoa, you save my brain after getting stuck for almost a week. Thank you.